# Actionscript 3 get last character from a text field

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

Hope someone can help me her. 
How can i get the value of the last character in a text field?

If the textfields value is "Hello World", i want to trace "d"

Answer (score 1):

If you only want a single character from a string, it might be better to use String.charAt() instead of String.substring() which is more for taking smaller strings out of other strings. It takes in a number for the character position you want, and in your case it would be the length of the string minus 1.

```
var aString:String = "Hello World";
aString.charAt(aString.length - 1)); // returns "d"
```

Answer (score 0):

use `substring`

like this:

```
var str1:String = "Hello World"; 

var str2:String =    str1.substr(-1);
```

> Result: "d"

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`String.substr`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/String.html#substr%28%29) :

```
trace("Hello World".substr(-1, 1));     // gives : d
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun, here's a third option:

```
var aString:String = "Hello World";
aString.split('')[ aString.length - 1 ]; // returns "d"
```

Split the string into an array of characters and take the element at the last index.